# PMD for detecting unused code - API usage

Tags: java, code-analysis, pmd

I have taken a look at the [PMD api](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/apidocs/overview-summary.html) which I want to use to detect unused instance variables and methods in a class. I see that it can be invoked from the command line, however I would like to perform a redundancy analysis of my class by invoking PMD programatically. Unfortunately, the api doesn't contain any information regarding the various classes and methods. Does anyone have any information regarding how PMD can be invoked to detect redundant code programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean invoke it as a part of your build? It wouldn't make much sense to invoke PMD to analyze the source code during the runtime of the actual application.

Take a look at [maven-pmd-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/) or [the Ant task](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ant-task.html).

Comment: I was looking to invoke PMD from a plugin (as a command) when a user right clicks on a source file. So I will be invoking PMD from a class in my plugin, not as part of the build.